# iTunes 11: Default Podcast settings

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I would like to change the default settings for all podcasts.

I know you can edit each one of them individually, but I would like to change the default for all to "Download All" and  keep "All episodes".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Right-click on any podcast and select *Settings*. Or if you are in list view, select the settings button in the lower-left corner:

[image]

- In the *Settings for:* drop-down list, select *Podcast Defaults*, then select *Download all* and *All episodes*:

[image]

- Make sure that all of your desired podcasts are using the new default settings by selecting each one from the drop-down list and checking that the  *Use Default Settings* checkbox is checked:

[image]

[image]

### Update:

iTunes 11.1.2 adds a new dialog for changing podcast settings. Select **Settings** and select **Defaults...** to change the default podcast settings.

[image]

### Update:

In iTunes 12.4.3.1 go to `Podcasts`, and click `Defaults` at the bottom of the list of your podcasts. Then you can set the default settings for all your podcasts (changed settings will also apply to existing ones if they're still set to default settings).

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: For cryin' out loud. I can't believe how far they buried this down.

Comment: The latest version of iTunes 11 changed this dialog completely. There is no "Settings for:" selector anymore, the dialog only contains settings for the selected podcast. *Now* how do we set the default settings?!! :-P

Answer (score 0):

patrix,

Try selecting NONE of the podcasts. Click on an empty spot in iTunes and then change "Settings..." That should change the defaults for podcasts you subscribe to in the future.