# On iTunes 11.4 where do you change the default settings for Podcasts?

Tags: itunes

I am using iTunes 11.4.x, and every time I add a new Podcast I have to change the settings.  Where can I change the default settings so any new podcasts I add will have the settings I want?

Comment: Is this not working for you http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/84129/46541

Answer (score 1):

There's a Default Settings link at the bottom of your list of Podcast subscriptions on the Podcasts page - you might have to scroll down the list to see it.